# Varios dominios a un Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Buen día.

Tengo una página en Wordpress para mi cliente, la página está hecha para funcionar con un dominio pero mi cliente tiene otros dos dominios adicionales, estos dominios también abren su página actual que está hecha en Joomla.

Yo le pase la web y la base de datos y las subió, al parecer los 3 dominios apuntan a esa misma carpeta pero obviamente sólo abre el dominio para el que está configurado el Wordpress, los otros 2 no abren la página.

Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Pues cambia el tuyo de sitio, y más si los otros dominios no son de wordpress. Seguramente tu cliente usa algun panel de gestión de su espacio que le permite crear dominios apuntando a carpetas distintas. Pues que lo haga y suba tu web a esa nueva carpeta y no lo mezcle todo en la misma, porque puede liar un cipostio de narices sobreescribiendo .htaccess e index.php por ejemplo. Seguramente ahora ya tendreis un lio para reconstruir lo que ya ha subido y que los jommla vuelvan a funcionar. Espero que tengais copias de ellos para encontrar los archivos reemplazados por la subida del wp

Comment: No cuenta con carpetas diferentes, el joomla es la web antigua, lo puse como ejemplo, ya que esa web estaba en una carpeta y se abría desde los 3 dominios. Lo que busco es la forma de que mi Wordpress abra desde los 3 dominios.

Comment: Ni idea pues, parece una cosa del wordpress más bien, y no lo uso apenas, lo siento.  Quizas este plugin te ayude: https://ca.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema concretamente? Ten en cuenta que Wordpress NO es un dominio, NO es una web, Wordpress es simplemente un manejador de contenidos y desde él puedes manejar un dominio o miles de dominios.

Comment: El problema es que mi cliente tiene 3 dominios:

www.dominio1.com
www.dominio2.com
www.dominio3.com

El tiene su antigua web en Joomla y cualquiera de estos 3 dominios abria la web sin problemas.

Yo hice su web en wordpress para el www.dominio1.com por que el me indico que ese era el dominio, cuando termino el trabajo me indica que tiene los otros 2 dominios mas, entonces como mi wordpress esta configurado para dominio1, los otros 2 no abren la web, si apuntan a la carpeta pero hay un problema de url y la web se ve toda descolocada.

Comment: Todavía no se entiende el problema. Hasta ahora sabemos que son tres dominios. ¿Esos tres dominios son independientes, cada uno con un contenido y una temática o apuntan todos a lo mismo (deben usar la misma base de datos, mostrar los mismos posts, etc)?

Comment: Apuntan a lo mismo, por ahora la solucion mas rapida es redireccionar esos dos dominios al principal, creo que asi quedara.

Comment: Si apuntan a lo mismo y tienen el mismo contenido, lo mejor es lo que acabas de decir, que todo vaya a uno. Y no por ahorrarte curro sino porque de la otra forma estabas duplicando el mismo contenido en todas las webs y eso perjudica al SEO de todas y además puede ser penalizado por google y otros buscadores por contenido duplicado.